Build AOSP Error cuttlefish::oemlock::OemLock has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
When I build Android Open Source Project for target aosp_cf_arm64_auto-userdebug , I face this error
device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock.h:29:7: error: 'cuttlefish::oemlock::OemLock' has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor [-Werror,-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
class OemLock {
^
1 error generated.
07:25:50 ninja failed with: exit status 1
The complete Error log is
[ 38% 58459/152771] //device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env:libsecure_env_linux clang++ oemlock_responder.cpp [linux_bionic]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/libsecure_env_linux/linux_bionic_arm64_static/obj/device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock_responder.o
PWD=/proc/self/cwd prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r487747c/bin/clang++ -c  -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-short-enums -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-stron
g -Wa,--noexecstack -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=format-security -nostdlibinc -fdebug-info-for-profiling -fp
ic -nostdlibinc -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wunreachable-code-loop-increment -no-canonical-prefixes -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -O2 -g -fdeb
ug-default-version=5 -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror=date-time -Werror=pragma-pack -Werror=pragma-pack-suspicious-include -Werror=string-plus-int -Werror=unreachable-code-loop-increment -Wno-error=deprecated-declar
ations -D__compiler_offsetof=builtin_offsetof -faddrsig -fcommon -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -fcolor-diagnostics -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-
gnu-designator -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wunguarded-availability -D__ANDROID_UNAVAILABLE_SYMBOLS_ARE_WEAK -ffp-contract=off -fdebug-prefix-map=/proc/self/cwd= -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -enable-trivial-auto
-var-init-zero-knowing-it-will-be-removed-from-clang -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -march=armv8-a -target aarch64-linux -DANDROID_STRICT -fPIC -Wsign-promo -Wimplicit-fallthrough -D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_THREAD_SAF
ETY_ANNOTATIONS -Wno-gnu-include-next   -Idevice/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env -Idevice/google/cuttlefish -Iexternal/scrypt/lib/crypto -Iexternal/ms-tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/Platform/include -Iexternal/ms-
tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/Platform/include/prototypes -Iexternal/ms-tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/Simulator/include -Iexternal/ms-tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/Simulator/include/prototypes -Iexternal/ms-tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/tpm/include -Iexternal
/ms-tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/tpm/include/Ossl -Iexternal/ms-tpm-20-ref/TPMCmd/tpm/include/prototypes -Iexternal/libcxx/include -Iexternal/libcxxabi/include -Iexternal/e2fsprogs/lib/blkid -Iexternal/e2fsprogs/lib -Isyst
em/libbase/include -Iexternal/fmtlib/include -Isystem/libcppbor/include/cppbor -Isystem/keymaster/include -Isystem/gatekeeper/include -Iexternal/jsoncpp/include -Ihardware/libhardware/include -Isystem/media/audi
o/include -Isystem/core/libcutils/include -Isystem/core/libsystem/include -Ipackages/modules/Bluetooth/system/types -Isystem/logging/liblog/include -Iexternal/boringssl/src/include -Isystem/core/libprocessgroup/
include -Iexternal/tpm2-tss/include -Iexternal/google-fruit/include -Iexternal/google-fruit/configuration/android -Ibionic/libc/async_safe/include -Ibionic/libc/system_properties/include -Isystem/core/property_s
ervice/libpropertyinfoparser/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm64 -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/android/scsi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/
android/uapi -fno-rtti -Werror -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCUTTLEFISH_HOST -std=c++17 -fno-rtti -Isystem/core/include -Isystem/logging/liblog/include -Isystem/media/audio/include -Ihardware/libhardware/includ
e -Ihardware/libhardware_legacy/include -Ihardware/ril/include -Iframeworks/native/include -Iframeworks/native/opengl/include -Iframeworks/av/include  -Werror=bool-operation -Werror=format-insufficient-args -Wer
ror=implicit-int-float-conversion -Werror=int-in-bool-context -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=xor-used-as-pow -Wno-void-pointer-to-enum-cast -Wno-void-pointer-to-int-cast -Wno-poi
nter-to-int-cast -Werror=fortify-source -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=return-type -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -Wno-tautological-type-limit-compare -Wno-reorder-init-list -W
no-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-tautological-overlap-compare -Wno-deprecated-copy -Wno-range-loop-construct -Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant -Wno-deprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-pessimizing-mov
e -Wno-non-c-typedef-for-linkage -Wno-align-mismatch -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-but-set-parameter -Wno-error=deprecated-builtins -Wno-error=deprecated -Wno-error=single-bit-bitfield-con
stant-conversion -Wno-error=enum-constexpr-conversion  -MD -MF out/soong/.intermediates/device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/libsecure_env_linux/linux_bionic_arm64_static/obj/device/google/cuttlefis
h/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock_responder.o.d -o out/soong/.intermediates/device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/libsecure_env_linux/linux_bionic_arm64_static/obj/device/google/cuttlefish/host/comm
ands/secure_env/oemlock_responder.o device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock_responder.cpp
In file included from device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock_responder.cpp:16:
In file included from device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock_responder.h:20:
device/google/cuttlefish/host/commands/secure_env/oemlock.h:29:7: error: 'cuttlefish::oemlock::OemLock' has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor [-Werror,-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
class OemLock {
^
1 error generated.
07:25:50 ninja failed with: exit status 1
failed to build some targets (07:19:02 (hh:mm:ss))

It means exactly what it says. Make the destructor virtual and the error will go away. Or remove -Werror=non-virtual-dtor flag.

You need to have a virtual destructor if the code deletes derived classes through a pointer to base class. Otherwise it's optional.
